# Broadcast received before UI is rendered

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-imageview, android-broadcast

In my application, I'm having a `ListView` which contains a `TextView` & one or more `ImageViews`.

Then I call a web-service, which in response gives me the content for TextView & a URL string of images (not the actual images).

I'm calling this webservice in `AsyncTask`.

In the `postExecute()`, I'm setting the TextView and then call a `Service` to fetch the image contents.

Inside the serivce, I'm using `ExecutorService` inside the for-loop to fetch the images one by one.

After all the images are downloaded in drive, I send a `broadcast` to notify my `fragment` that all the images are downloaded.

In the fragment's `onReceive()`, I set images in the `ImageViews`.

Issue is sometimes, the call to onReceive() is made even before the ImageView is rendered.

So I get a `NullPointerException` on ImageView.

How can I solve this problem.

I'm not willing to integrate any 3rd party library unless really have to.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean uiReady = false;
boolean imagesReady = false;

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(uiReady){
        // Set images
    }
    else {
        imagesReady = true;
    }
}
}

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            if(imagesReady){
                // Set images
            }
            else {
                uiReady = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

where/when in the [activity-lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is the start of the AsyncTask that does the webservice call?

if the start is the last statement in the `onCreate` after the ImageViews have been set up your problem should have disappeared